# Angular/JavaScript Ag Grid define cell class rules

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

Looking for way to change style of particular cell in Ag-Grid using Angular.
Say we have column 'Amount' if cell value of that column in any row is blank, I want to make that cell background-color = Pink (or any)

Have tried using Ag Grid cellStyle and cellClassRules but its not reflecting the css class which i want to use...

How to border-left-color to ag grid particular cell i am using class but its not reflecting

How to do that ?
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.

Comment: @Paritosh - updated

Comment: @Angelina Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: @wentjun - its resolved, thanks for asking though :)
can you have a look at this once - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666503/ag-grid-tree-like-structure-attach-cellclass-to-nodechildren-cells-based-on-vali