# Ag-Grid Tree like structure attach cellClass to NodeChildren cells based on validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ag-grid

In my Jquery&JavaScript, Angular, all seperate applications i have included Ag-Grid with columnDefs like below :-

```
 this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Age",
    field: "age",
    cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Name",
    field: "name"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Year",
    field: "year"
  },
  {
    headerName: "Country",
    field: "country"
  }
];
```

and my row Data is like below

```
 this.rowData = [
  {
    age: "Group A",
    participants: [
      {
        age: 1,
        name: "Michael Phelps",
        year: "2008",
        country: "United States"
      },
      {
        name: "A.2",
        age: 2,
        year: "2008",
        country: "United States"
      },
      {
        name: "A.3",
        age: 50,
        year: "2008",
        country: "United States"
      }
    ]}];

this.getNodeChildDetails = function getNodeChildDetails(rowItem) {
  if (rowItem.participants) {
    return {
      group: true,
      children: rowItem.participants,
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
```

Now i want to attach cellClass to children grid values based on validation, like:-

```
 if(age< 23 || ''){
  return['classNameThatiWantToAttach'];
 }
```

How to do this ??

You can make changes in below plunker also for this: -

https://plnkr.co/edit/lmjtuqfId4FIsTI5luL8?p=preview

Comment: just to inform rowData here in my application i will be getting from angular http service, will not be using JSON like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

edit the column definitions and add a cellClass function to it

```
 {
    headerName: "Year",
    field: "year",
    editable: true,
    cellClass: this.cellClass
  }
```

Then define the function and add the conditions you need and return a string with the value of the class

```
  cellClass(params) {
    if (params.value >= 2015)
      return "redClass"
  }
```

Don't forget to add the css styling for the classes.

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZMWjgvm3o0LqZYnDAXoX?p=preview)

Comment: validateAge() {
          return (params) => {
           console.log(params);
          return params.node.data.year === 2010;
       };
  }

I made this change it worked on your plunker but not working for me in application

Comment: You can check params.data to get any other column value inside the function.

Comment: thanks i am getting the other column values which i want but its value is like - "age_Invalid|year_invalid" in console, now from here i want to do something like this - params.data.invalidDetails.includes(params.colDef.field) { return 'className' }

Comment: i am unable to ask question now - can you look at this plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/lmjtuqfId4FIsTI5luL8?p=preview

and tell me how to include validation class on selected fields based on value of invalidDetails field

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated plunkr showing a cell in red color as per validation of the age:

https://plnkr.co/edit/QZd2MM1LflQaruxdCmym?p=preview

```
this.columnDefs = [
    // ...
    {
        headerName: "Age",
        field: "age",
        cellClassRules: this.getCssClass()
    }
    // ...
];

getCssClass(): {[cssClassName: string]: (Function | string)} {
    return {
        'invalid-age': this.validateAge(),
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for implementing it, but is it possible to update class based on other cell value ??  like in your case - if(country === 'United States') { then apply class to YEAR Cell }